# Toolbar in pagecurl not loaded

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar, page-curl

I am implementing the half pagecurl feature. It is working fine. But I want the new page to have the same toolbar as that of the curled page. Right now I cant get it right. Any help will be appreciated. I have also checked whether I have set the toolbar as hidden.

```
pageCurlViewController = [[MapViewPageCurlViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewPageCurlViewController" bundle:nil];
[pageCurlViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[self presentModalViewController:pageCurlViewController animated:YES];
```

This is the code I am using to load the page curl feature. Now, to load the toolbar programmatically, what should I add to this code.

Answer (score 0):

If the toolbar belongs to the curled page and you are presenting a modal view with modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl, then the modal view will hide the original one and covers the toolbar. You have to add a toolbar to the modal view.

You can copy the array of items from the original toolbar to the one of the modal view using "items" and "setItems:animated:" before presenting the modal view.

Comment: The toolbar is not loaded mate. I have set the hidden property of the toolbar to no . But still it is not loaded.

Comment: I'm loosing something. The modal view does include a toolbar as part of the view or not? The toolbar view must be part of the modal view. If it's not loaded is 'cause it's not part of the view that is appearing. Check the xib file.

Comment: I have set the bottom bar of the viewcontroller view as toolbar

Comment: But toolbar property doesn't works for a modal view. That prop is for viewcontrollers on navigation controllers.

Comment: @ So how could I load a toolbar in this case.

Comment: Toolbar must be a subview of the modal view. That is what I tried to say before. The easy way is putting a toolbar on the view in the xib file. If you prefer to add it programmatically, then addSubview: is the obvious solution.